# playframework read json from post

Tags: java, json, playframework

I want to read a json sent to my controller via post.

When I do this:

```
System.out.println(request().body());
```

Result is:

```
DefaultRequestBody(None,None,None,None,None,Some(MultipartFormData(Map(json -> List({"a":"Test","b":"sssd"})),List(),List(),List())))
```

Now I will follow this documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaJsonActions

And I do this:

```
System.out.println(request().body().asJson());
```

Result is:

```
NULL
```

How can I access my json?

I also tried this:

```
Http.MultipartFormData multipartFormData  = request().body().asMultipartFormData();

System.out.println(request().body());
System.out.println(request().body().asMultipartFormData());

System.out.println(multipartFormData.asFormUrlEncoded().get("a"));
```

It also returns `null`

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a possible solution is

```
Http.RequestBody body = request().body();
JsonNode json = body.asJson();

System.out.println(json);
```